# Is there an international call/SMS solution that uses plain calling and texting

Tags: phone, sms

I'm looking for an international call/sms solution that has the following features:

- I want to make/receive international phone calls that are free for
  the other person. I don't mind paying myself to make/receive the calls.
- I want to have international sms conversations that are free for the    other person. I don't mind paying myself to send/receive the messages.
- I want to do this by calling/smsing a regular number from my phone. I don't want to have to use an app.

Things I don't need:

- I *don't* need the number I call/sms to be the actual number of the person I'm contacting (i.e. some kind of forwarding system is fine).
- I *don't* need the number my friend calls/smses to be my actual phone number.

Any suggestions for the above?